# Body submerged in two liquids

Tags: fluid-mechanics

A metallic cube of side 10cm, density 6.8gm/cc is floating in liquid mercury (density 13.6gm/cc), with 5cm height of cube exposed above mercury level. Water is filled over this to submerge the cube fully. What is the new height of the cube exposed above the mercury level?

Comment: Looks like a homework question. What work have you done to try to solve this question?

Comment: I have gone through the concepts, i know that the block will rise up. But by how much is what i am not able to figure out.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it's homework, and no initial effort has been demonstrated.

Comment: Welcome to Engineering! This looks like a [homework question](http://meta.engineering.stackexchange.com/q/121/1832). In order for such questions to be answered in this site, we need you to add details describing the precise problem you're having. What have you tried to solve this yourself? Please [edit] your question to include this information.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Question was really simple, **We need to equate the total buoyancy force with the weight of the body**. I was stuck with before and after situation so was not able to solve it. Answer is the block will rise by 0.4cm.

Total Buoyancy force for a body immersed in two fluid 
= Density of water*g(S1*V1+S2*V2)

V1 & V2 being volume of block in respective fluid. S1 and S2 specific gravity

In this question 1-Mercury, 2-water

When water is filled over mercury, let us assume that the block will rise by a x units.

Buoyancy force= 1000*g(S1*(5-x)+S2(5+x))= Weight of block.

Comment: this is really not an adequate answer. It is fair to self-answer your own question but you should show the steps.  If you feel it is too trivial to be of use to anyone else then you should delete the question.